# How i can Remove Data from redux automatic using setTimeOut

Tags: redux, react-redux

Hiii i have one array like more than one object and when store data from redux i need to remove automatic from array after 5 second.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the community! For your problem maybe use a useEffect hook in the app component, eg:

```
import foo from "foo.js";
import blahblahblah from "xxx.js";
import React from "react";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
// ..;

function App(){

const dispatch = useDispatch();

React.useEffect(()=>{
while(true){
setTimeout(()=>{
dispatch.runSomthing(myAmazingData);
},5000);
}
}, []);
return(
<div>
<p>Welcome to my amazing website</p>
</div>)
}

export default App;
```

Next time, show some code! And explain your intentions and what you want to do.

Thanks!